# How to integrate : $\int \frac{\cos x}{(1+e^x)}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

How to integrate :

$\int \frac{\cos x}{(1+e^x)}dx$

I don't have any clue on this, please guide how to solve such problems , Thanks

Comment: Where did you find this one? As it stands right now, it looks like something randomly made up, and such integrals do in general not have elementary primitives. Or, could it be, that you look for the integral from $0$ to $+\infty$ or something similar?

Comment: Are the limits from $-1$ to $1$

Comment: This integral is so close to $\int u(-x)\cos(x)dx $ there's not much point in tangling with the hypergeometric functions that the exact integral yields, if this is for some real, physical problem.

Comment: The integral from $0$ to $\infty$ can be represented as the real part of the subtraction of two Harmonic Numbers, which *might* simplify further.

Comment: Are you interested in the general primitive or just in the integral over $\mathbb{R}^+$?

Comment: The digamma function $\psi(z)=\frac{d}{dz}\log\Gamma(z)=\frac{\Gamma'(z)}{\Gamma(z)}$ is deeply involved anyway.